# Getting csv header in pandas from arbitrary row

Tags: pandas

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
s,k,i,p   # 0. N rows to skip
H,E,A,D   # 1. header names
n,o,n,e   # 2. N more rows to skip
1,2,3,4   # 3. Data
6,7,8,9   # 4. ...
...       # 5. ...
```

Can I read this data in with a single call to `pandas.read_csv`? I'm having trouble because I can't seem to **skip rows until the header** then **skip more rows until the data**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass a list of rows to skip to `skiprows` like so:

```
In [2]:pd.read_csv('the_file.csv', skiprows=[0,2])
Out[2]:
   H  E  A  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  6  7  8  9
```